# htmlspecialchars() is causing a variable to return blank data?

Tags: php, html-entities, html-encode, htmlspecialchars

I am pulling data from a database using mysqli and PHP.

This works OK but I get a random character (black question mark) replacing apostrophes in words, so I thought I could use the `htmlspecialchars()` function to have them display properly, but it doesn't work.

So my code looks like this

```
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
{
    $desc = htmlspecialchars($row['description'], ENT_QUOTES);?>

    <div class="timeline-key">
        <div class="fluid key-content">
            <p><?php echo $desc?></p>
        </div>
    </div><?php
}
```

Now any record in the database which contains an apostrophe $desc prints out nothing, all other records print out OK?

Now if I try the exact same come on a string that is not being pulled from the database it displays it OK?

Comment: Surely, you can provide the relevant parts of the resulting HTML file.

Comment: yeah sorry, have amended the post and included a link to the website also. thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the website you linked, it is obvious that the page itself uses UTF-8 for character encoding (`<meta charset="UTF-8">`). It seems that the database from which you fetch your data uses a character encoding that is not equal to the `ini_get("default_charset")` value. [If you get the encoding wrong, `htmlspecialchars` will return the empty string](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php#refsect1-function.htmlspecialchars-returnvalues), which is what you're seeing here.

The solution is to be consistent in (or explicit about) which character encoding you're using. This is a lot simpler when you use one character encoding for everything. Let's use UTF-8 as a good example:

- **Tell the browser you're using UTF-8.** You already do that with the meta tag, so that's good.
- **[Tell PHP you're using UTF-8](/questions/9351694/setting-php-default-encoding-to-utf-8).** Make sure that php.ini sets `default_charset` to `UTF-8`.
- **[Tell MySQL you're using UTF-8](/questions/202205/how-to-make-mysql-handle-utf-8-properly).** Make sure the tables in your database use UTF-8 as their encoding *-edit- or tell the MySQL interface to use UTF-8.*

Alternatively, you could use a function like [`mb_convert_encoding`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-convert-encoding.php) to convert the strings between the different character encodings that the browser is expecting, that PHP is assuming, and that MySQL uses to store and serve text.

Comment: thank you for your detailed reply, i understand what is going on now. as you said i have told the browser to use UTF-8 now i have added the following to see what the default charset for php is: echo ini_get("default_charset"); and that returns UTF-8 so now its just down to the database itself. which I'm having trouble checking. am awaiting my host to get back to me to see what the current charset is

Comment: ok i have just checked my sql charset using var_dump($conn->get_charset()); and that returned object(stdClass)#2 (8) { ["charset"]=> string(6) "latin1" ["collation"]=> string(17) "latin1_swedish_ci" ["dir"]=> string(0) "" ["min_length"]=> int(1) ["max_length"]=> int(1) ["number"]=> int(8) ["state"]=> int(1) ["comment"]=> string(0) "" } which shows that mysql charset is latin1_swedish_ci so that is obviously the issue here. currently trying to set a new charset for mysql

Comment: Query the information schema, as explained [in this answer](/a/1049958/824425).

Comment: sorted it!!! added the following line mysqli_set_charset($conn,"utf8"); and now all of the 3 are set to UTF-8 thank you very much!!!!!!